# Hibernate JPA Transient Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to use Hibernate JPA to return a Result Set (RS) from multiple entities, but the returned RS is not a persistence entity in itself?

For Example (pseudo code):

Persistence Entity ***One*** has fields `A` , `B` , `Oneflag`

Persistence Entity ***Two*** has fields `C` , `D` , `Twoflag`

Persistence Entity ***Three*** has fields `E` , `F` , `Threeflag`

I am looking for something like

```
@Query(value ="Select A, C, E from One o, Two tw, Three th 
where o.oneFlag = tw.TwoFlag and
o.oneFlag = th.ThreeFlag", ***nativeQuery*** = true)

List<MyRsClass> findByFlag(@Param(aFlag) String aFlag);
```

and my non Persistence class is:

```
Class MyRsClass {
  String A;
  String C;
  String E
  .....
}
```

I certainly can accomplish this  if I create `MyRsClass` ad a table in the DB, but I am trying to avoid this.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Result Class is a JPA standard and in your case you would alter the query:

```
@Query(value ="Select new com.mypackage.MyRsClass(A, C, E) from One o, Two tw, Three th 
where o.oneFlag = tw.TwoFlag and
o.oneFlag = th.ThreeFlag",
```

Remember to:

- Specify constructor with appropriate ordering of params
- Use the fully qualified class name in the query

Comment: Thanks a million.  I was not aware of this.  Regarding the constructor for MyRsClass, I have public MyRsClass(Long A, String C, String E) { this.A = A ....}  but I get error Parameter 0 of constructor in ...MyRsClass  required a bean of type 'Long' that could not be found.   Any idea how to resolve?   I did annotate the class as @Componenet

Comment: you have to make sure that the constructor has param types so that they match the column types from the select.. aparently you need to expect a Long in the first param

Comment: Hi ... I am not sure I understand this part "you have to make sure that the constructor has param types so that they match the column types from the select.".   I checked and they do.  Is there a full example somewhere where I review.   The error shows in the IDE as soon as I add the constructor ... but without constructor I can't go forward.

Comment: maybe you should change the first param to a String

Comment: also as this is not a native query, try to add aliased so .. o.A, o.B, tw.C